# Receive data through JSON endpoint

Tags: php, json, curl

i need to receive data through JSON Endpoint in PHP, can anyone help me please?

How can i receive data through this:

curl https://formz.herokuapp.com/api/forms/e382704d/submissions -H 'Authorization: Token token="xxxxxxxxxxxxx"'

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i just tryed receive with file_get_contents, but not work. @CodeGodie

Comment: note: Don't post auth tokens on public forums

Comment: Thanks @old_mountain, but this is only test API, not production.

Answer (score 0):

Using `curl` and `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`

```
$ch = curl_init();
$headers = array('Authorization: Token token="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://formz.herokuapp.com/api/forms/e382704d/submissions");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

print $output;
```

Should give you the output

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

Just it.

```
$access_key = 'TOKEN HERE';

$curl = curl_init( 'https://formz.herokuapp.com/api/forms/e382704d/submissions' );

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Authorization: Token ' . $access_key ) );

curl_exec( $curl );
```